# symbolically/parametric solving a nonlinear equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, nonlinear-functions, symbolic-computation

I have these two equations where `x, y` and `z` are variables and `p1, p2` and `p3` are parameter. Can MATLAB find parametric/symbolic solutions for `x y z` based on `p1, p2, p3`?

- `2(x−p1)+2(xy−p3)y = 0`
- `2(y−p2)+2(xy−p3)x = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put yes.  Take all of your variables, use [`syms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) to define each of your variables so that they are symbolic variables, then use [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) to solve the equation for you.  You specify the two equations as two parameters into `solve`.  The output (which we will store in `sol`) will return a structure that contains an `x` field and a `y` field, as your equation is defined with respect to two variables, and `p1,p2,p3` are parameters.  In other words, do this:

```
syms p1 p2 p3;
syms x y;
sol = solve(2*(x-p1)+2*(x*y-p3)*y == 0, 2*(y-p2)+2*(x*y-p3)*x == 0);
```

You can access the solution of what `x` and `y` are by accessing each of their respective fields:

```
>> sol.x

ans =

(p1^3 + p3*p1^2*z1 + p1*z1^4 - 1.0*p2*p1*z1^3 + p1*z1^2 - 1.0*p2*p1*z1 + p3*z1^3 - 1.0*p2*p3*z1^2 + p3*z1 - 1.0*p2*p3)/(p1^2 + p3^2)

>> sol.y

ans =

z1
```

You will get a warning though, stating that the solution is parametrized by symbols, but that is to be expected.  Specifically:

```
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
z1 = RootOf(z^5 - p2*z^4 + 2*z^3 - z^2*(2*p2 - p1*p3) + z*(p1^2 - p3^2 + 1) - p1*p3 - p2, z)
```

Comment: thanks rayryeng, I understand z1, but I dont know where z appears from?

Comment: where is z coming from?

Comment: @MathewPalsberg - `z` is a parameter that you vary as there are infinitely many solutions that satisfy the equation.  As such, replace `z1` with what you see in the statement above.  `z` is any value of your choosing.

Comment: @MathewPalsberg - You're very welcome.  Please accept my answer if this has helped you!  Go to the top of my post, and to the left below the up and down vote buttons, click on the checkmark icon.  This symbolizes that you don't need help anymore and this has been resolved.  Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @rayryeng Please note that there are not infinitely many solutions due to `z`'s infinite number of possible values. The solution is the root of an equation in `z` unknown (hence `RootOf`); the said equation depends on the parameters `p*`.

Comment: I was wondering, couldnt Matlab solve a parametric/symbolic  quintic(degree of 5) equation?@CST-Link @rayryeng

Comment: @MathewPalsberg - Yes it could, but you have parameters `p1,p2,p3` and so the solution will change depending on what `p*` are.

Comment: Really? So why Matlab couldnt find the root of quintic(degree of 5) z1 above? shouldnt be able to give 1 to 5 roots based on P1,P2, and P3?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. Maybe @CST-Link can explain it better. Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng As you might know, there is no general formula for ordinary algebraic equation of 5th or greater degree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem So MATLAB does the best it can do, i.e. show you the equation for the roots.

Comment: @MathewPalsberg Please see the above answer to the comment of rayryeng